# How to use laravel Auth::user() outside laravel and pass data in custom php?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to implement [simogeo filemanager](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager) into laravel and using it in combination with tinymce i will use it without tinymce also but that's not the problem.

I have already configured setup and installed all, and it works fine so far, but last one step is to make sure that only authorized users can call filemanager and upload files, and also there is an option to filemanager to have user specific folders. For that i will have to pass Auth::user() from laravel and check if user is loged in, and also if i use Auth::user()->username i would be able to have user specific folders.

Is there a way to pass Auth::user() for outside script from laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use route filter ,

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
     Route::get('filemanager', 'FileManager');

});
```

Comment: Well that solves a part of the problem, i already did that, this prevents non registered users to access filemanager, and also it gives a route to filemanager. but the problem still exists with this, once you are registered you can access filemanager and manage each other images.